# What key is "<Primary>"?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, gtk

I just saw a weird shortcut in `dconf-editor`:

```
<Primary><Alt>KP_End
```

What is `<Primary>`?

I also saw an `Above-Tab` key. I completely understand what that refers to, but where are those key-names defined?

This also applies to XFCE and `xfconf-query`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`<Primary>` is a `gtk+` thing.
`gtk+ 2.24.7` & `gtk+ 3.2.1` introduced the concept of a platform-agnostic accelerator modifier, `<Primary>`, which can be used instead of `<Control>`:

> *a new facility is provided in Gtk+ (as of this writing it is in Git for Gtk+-2.24, and released in Gtk+-3.2.0) to use the `<Primary>`
>   descriptor in place of `<Control>` for accelerators and bindings. This
>   will map the accelerator to Command on OSX and to Control for anything
>   else.*<sup>[1](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-September/msg06655.html)</sup>

As per this [commit](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-September/msg06655.html):

> *gtk: allow to specify accelerators in a platform-independent way. Introduce `<Primary>` in accelerator strings, which resolves to
>   GDK_CONTROL_MASK on X11/Win23, and to GDK_META_MASK on quartz.*

it is defined (along with other accelerators) in [`gtkaccelgroup.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkaccelgroup.c)

```c
gtk_accelerator_name (guint accelerator_key,
                     GdkModifierType accelerator_mods)
{
  static const gchar text_release[] = "<Release>";
  static const gchar text_primary[] = "<Primary>";
  static const gchar text_shift[] = "<Shift>";
  static const gchar text_control[] = "<Control>";
  static const gchar text_mod1[] = "<Alt>";
  static const gchar text_mod2[] = "<Mod2>";
  static const gchar text_mod3[] = "<Mod3>";
  static const gchar text_mod4[] = "<Mod4>";
  static const gchar text_mod5[] = "<Mod5>";
  static const gchar text_meta[] = "<Meta>";
  static const gchar text_super[] = "<Super>";
  static const gchar text_hyper[] = "<Hyper>";
```

---

`<Above_tab>` is a window manager thing.
As per this [commit](https://gitorious.org/metacity/metacity/commit/859d214a04c29ec839d5552f3e13dff937260083) in `metacity`:

> *We want switching between the windows of an application to be an easily accessible operation. The convenient and memorable keybinding
>   is the key above the tab key - but the keysym for that key isn't
>   consistent across different keyboard layouts. Add code that figures
>   out the key from the XKB geometry and a magic keysym name "Above_Tab"
>   that refers to this key and switch the default binding for cycle_group
>   to Above_Tab*

See also this [commit](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2014-April/msg01736.html) in `mutter` and source files [`meta-accel-parse.c`](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/master/src/core/meta-accel-parse.c) and [`meta-accel-parse.h`](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/master/src/core/meta-accel-parse.h)

Comment: Gosh, how confusing. Do you mean it’s normally a GNOME thing, except that Above-Tab and Primary are mutter-only?? (I.e. only mutter can understand shortcut descriptions containing those?)